# New to React (Beginner)

Tags: reactjs

I wrote a code in React

```js
function Card() {
  return (
  <card>
    <div>
      <h2 className={ "dad"}>Nitin Muley</h2>
      <img src={ "https://freeimage.host/i/HaMOhCu"} />
      <p>+91 123 456 7890</p>
      <p>xyz@gmail.com</p>
    </div>
  </card>
  );
}
```

When I changed the `<card><card>` to `<Card></Card>` in the return function my react app crashes.

I didn't understand as to why did this happen.

I tried making changes to the code cause my console was stating a warning:The tag `<card>` is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.

And when I changed the `<card>` to `<Card>` the app snaps immediately.

Comment: You seem to be using `<Card/>` inside the definition of the Card component?

Comment: if you change <card> into <Card> you are recursively including the component itself

Comment: If rendering a `<Card>` involves rendering a `<Card>` then what you have is an infinite recursion.  Why do you want that?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Since your current component is named `Card` if you use it inside it it will create an infinite loop.

Comment: I am new to the world of coding, so I made mistake. I am still learning. And thank you for helping Sir.

Comment: I am trying my hands-on, on the course I completed till date of React JS. Hence, was practicing and trying to create a simple web page using react.

Comment: You can just return a <div> and when you "call" this component you can use <Card />

Answer (score 0):

You have confused some things

The `<Card>` is calling the function Card() and that function is not imported and not valid and e.t.c.

How it works is:

1. You create the function Card()
2. You import it in another code or in another part of the code in which you want to use the function Card() e.g. `import Cart from './thePathForTheCallFunction'`
3. You call the function Card() by typing `<Cart></Cart>` or `<Cart/>`

Now in your code you have the following bugs:

```
function Card() {
  return (
  <card> //you do not need this 
    <div>
      <h2 className={ "dad"}>Nitin Muley</h2> //you don't need the {} for just a string
      <img src={ "https://freeimage.host/i/HaMOhCu"} /> //you can not do this for the src, you need to use require or import the file
      <p>+91 123 456 7890</p>
      <p>xyz@gmail.com</p>
    </div>
  </card> // you do not need this 
  );
}
```

And the correct code is:

```
function Card() {
  return (   
    <div>
      <h2 className="dad">Nitin Muley</h2>
      <img src={require("https://freeimage.host/i/HaMOhCu")} alt="image"/> 
      <p>+91 123 456 7890</p>
      <p>xyz@gmail.com</p>
    </div>  
  );
}
```

Now you can use this function as many times you want in another code or in part of the code.

Comment: Just to round this out, the implementation would be a `<Card>` tag somewhere in your html or jsx code.